# Can I compute AUC value and ROC curve from AutoML Vision by Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, classification, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

May I know how can I compute AUC value and ROC curve from an AutoML Vision trained model? Google does only provide the average precision and Precision-Recall curve for evaluation (including a confusion matrix). May I know are there methods in dealing this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment AutoML Vision does not provide this feature to get [AUC value and ROC](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc), I suggest you to file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) asking for this feature.

Keep in mind that there is no ETA for approve/implement Feature Requests as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

After doing it I suggest you to “starring" that feature request to vote and supply feedback about how it would be useful. I also suggest you verify constantly the Cloud Vision release notes to know about all features, bug fixes, known issues, and deprecated functionality on [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/release-notes).

Comment: Thanks so much! May I ask another question? After I have trained a model in automl vision, it reported with a precision-recall curve and a confusion matrix. I would like to know what is the threshold being set to depict the confusion matrix? I cannot find any documentation in Google Cloud stating the threshold value for the construction of that particular confusion matrix. Many thanks!